# Mongodb set index on insert many Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am working on wrapping my head around mongodb and wrote a simple function that takes a realtime feed and inserts the json into a mongodb collection, which is working, which i have included below. The data feed is a vehicle tracking feed so the gps data is streaming in real time.

```
  import urllib2, json, sched, time,requests
  from pymongo import MongoClient

  s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
  def runUpdate(sc): 
        url='www.myrealtimedatafeed'
        json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = json.load(json_obj)
        connection = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost/database')
        db = connection.test

        result = db.records.insert_many(data['result'])
        ##for item in data['result']:
        ##    print item['device']['id']
        ##    print item['dateTime']
        ##    print item['latitude']
        ##    print item['longitude']
        s.enter(30, 1, runUpdate, (sc,))
  s.enter(30, 1, runUpdate, (s,))
  s.run()
```

Now i have two scenarios playing out in my head that I may need help on. Now my intent is to use a scheduler to rerun this ever 30 seconds or so for both scenarios.

The first scenario that I need to keep inserting records as time goes by, so for each device id there would be an new insert every 30 seconds, so I guess this would always be an insert since the dateTime field would be my index? How would create that field and set it as an index on insert?

The second scenario, I need to keep replacing the records based on device id so there would always only be one record for each device id, which would be it's current lat and long. This I guess would need to be a multi update and the device id would be the index?

In mongodb how would i set the index on insert many? I believe after everything, that would be the solution to both scenarios?

Thank you in advance

EDITED:

ok, so to answer my own question about the indexing, in the mongo shell using

```
db.createCollection("myCollectionName", {autoIndexId:false})
```

I then created my dateTime index and my documents started loading in based on this new index. I also did the same on deviceID on another collection.

i do wonder why when creating a collection, you aren't able to define the index

Answer (score 0):

Note that `autoIndexId` option in [db.createCollection()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) has been deprecated since MongoDB version 3.2 (currently version 3.4.x).

To clarify, this option is to disable setting the default id field `_id` to be indexed. Currently with this option you can create a collection without an index, which is not recommended in [MongoDB replica set deployment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/).

> In mongodb how would i set the index on insert many?

You don't generally create an index on [insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/). Instead you should use [createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/), which can be performed after the collection creation. Note that you can build index(es) on the [background](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/) as well as on the foreground (default).

Depending on your use case and deployment environment, I would suggest to use the first scenario. This is suitable for:

- The system keeps the history location of the devices (not being replaced)
- The database only accepts write operations, instead of read and write.

If you're planning to [shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) your deployment later on, worth considering that if you are indexing only on date (time), this is a monotonically increasing key value. See also [Monotonically Changing Shard Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys)